# Are there parsers that can parse languages in more expressive grammars than context-free grammars?

Tags: computability, parsing

The [Earley Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) is able to parse all context-free languages. Are there parsers that can parse say languages in context-sensitive grammars? I realize ambiguous grammars are non-deterministic and might make this question not well formed and would be ready accept an answer that explains why it is not well formed if so.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Equivalence_to_linear_bounded_automaton

Comment: @D.W. I've already read that part of the page. So It's still an open problem to create parsers for more expressive grammars? AFAIK a LBA is not a parsing algorithm, it's a hypothetical machine that can accept or reject a set of strings.

Comment: You can write an LBA interpreter in any sufficiently expressive programming language, so the LBA construction does give an algorithm.